# Adding SQLite database value to ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to add SQLite database value to ListView if record exists, but I'm only getting text from EditText.

Here's what I'm doing

Code from databaseHelper Class

```
public String ifExistIn(String stationName) {

    String query = "SELECT stationName FROM review WHERE stationId='" + stationName + "' LIMIT 1";
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null));
        return stationName;
    }
}
```

Code from activity class

```
public View.OnClickListener searchStation = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        String searchString= searchText.getText().toString();
        dbHelper.ifExistIn(searchString);

        list.add(searchString);
        arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchAndReview.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't check return value of `ifExistsIn()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a few mistakes here but from what I can see you can try this:

```
public String ifExistIn(String stationName) {

    String query = "SELECT stationName FROM review WHERE stationId='" + stationName + "' LIMIT 1";
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("stationName"));
}
```

You have to get the result of the Cursor and interpret it then return it AS `String stationName`.

And this:

```
public View.OnClickListener searchStation = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    String searchString= searchText.getText().toString();

    String usethis = dbHelper.ifExistIn(searchString);

    list.add(usethis);
    arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchAndReview.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
};
```

You're getting `searchString` and putting it into your list and not doing anything with the result of your query. You need to assign the result of your query somewhere then use it. Or actually just directly use it in the insert like:

```
list.add(dbHelper.ifExistsIn(searchString);
```

Comment: Application is crashing when i follow this

Comment: Unfortunately application has stopped

Comment: Anything from logcat? We need to see the error you're getting so we know where the problem is and can address it.

Comment: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: I added `cur.moveToFirst()`, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like this:

```
public String ifExistIn(String stationName){

        String query = "SELECT stationName FROM review WHERE stationId='" + stationName + "' LIMIT 1";
        try{
            SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null))
            return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("columnName"));
        }


    }
```

You need to extract data from **cursor** object. Now you are returning a same value which you are passing.